# How to remove safely remove USB which has Ubuntu running on it

Tags: boot, usb

I just installed Ubuntu onto a USB, so that I can use it on any computer. I managed to boot from it, but I'm not sure how to safely remove the USB now since I can't safely eject it if the OS is running from it. Can I just restart the PC and change boot order back to windows and just remove the USB, or is there some precautionary step I need to take to not lose the data on the USB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutdown Ubuntu running a live session from the USB by clicking the ⏻ icon in the upper right corner of the desktop. From the dropdown menu select *Poweroff / Log Out*  -> *Power Off* -> In the *Power Off* dialog window that pops up click the *Power Off* button. Shutting down the USB Ubuntu live session will also power off the computer. Then you can safely remove the Ubuntu live USB from the USB port without losing any data on the USB.

There is another way to safely remove the USB drive without shutting down the computer. Restart the computer instead of shutting down and press the key that enters the BIOS/UEFI setup utility. In the BIOS/UEFI it is possible to safely remove the Ubuntu live USB and then press the key that exits from the BIOS/UEFI setup utility without saving any changes. After exiting from the BIOS the computer will continue to boot as usual.